# Does every regular Noetherian domain have finite Krull dimension?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Does every regular Noetherian domain have finite Krull dimension?

**Background**: A Noetherian ring is said to be regular if its localizations at all prime (or maximal) ideals are regular local rings. Without this assumption, there are counter-examples.

Comment: All the examples of regular Noetherian domains are coordinate rings of some nice (finite-dimensional) variety, in which case the result is obvious.

Comment: @Alex: how about the ring $\mathbb Z$? (Not that it is infinite-dimensional, but I would not say "all teh examples":)

Comment: @Serge Whoops, I meant to say "I tend to think of".

Comment: It is not clear to me "without" which "assumption" do you mean? Do you mean without noetherian assumption? As far as I know, the definition of a regular *local* ring includes noetherian. Are you asking for a *non-noetherian* ring whose local rings are regular (thus noetherian) local rings?

Comment: No, I meant that without the regularity assumption, there are examples of noetherian domains of infinite Krull dimension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. An example is given in K. Fujita, [*Infinite dimensional Noetherian Hilbert domains,*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/hiroshima-mathematical-journal/volume-5/issue-2/Infinite-dimensional-Noetherian-Hilbert-domains/10.32917/hmj/1206136627.full) Hiroshima Math. J. 5 (1975), 181-185.

Comment: How about the example of Nagata given in Exercise 4 of Chapter 11 of Atiyah-MacDonald?

Comment: @nosr: cf. Neil's answer and my comment on it.

Answer (score 10):

Here's my favorite example (is this the one nosr refers to in his comment? I'm pretty sure it's also due to Nagata).  Let $k$ be a field and $A=k[x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots]$ be polynomial ring in countably many variables.  Let $P_1 := (x_1)$, $P_2 := (x_2, x_3)$, $P_3 := (x_4, x_5, x_6)$, and in general $P_n$ is generated by the "next" $n$ variables.  That is, $P_n := \left(x_{{n \choose 2} + 1}, x_{{n \choose 2} + 2}, \ldots, x_{{n+1} \choose 2}\right)$.  Let $W := A \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty P_n$, and let $R := W^{-1}A$.  Then every prime ideal of $R$ is in some $P_nR$, each of which is a maximal ideal of $R$, and $R_{P_n R} \cong k[y_1, \dotsc, y_n]_{(y_1, \dotsc, y_n)}$ is certainly a regular local ring.  Hence $R$ is a regular Noetherian ring.  But as it has essentially polynomial rings of every dimension as localizations, $R$ has infinite dimension.

On the other hand, every Noetherian *local* ring has finite Krull dimension.

Comment: This is indeed (a special case of) the original Example 1 in the Appendix of Nagata's _Local rings._ Your last sentence might be confusing, as it remains true without the word "regular".

Comment: Good point, Fred.  I have edited it accordingly.

Comment: "Hence $R$ is a regular Noetherian ring" - Well, noetherian cannot be checked stalkwise, and here it really requires some work.

Comment: @Martin: A slick way to handle the noetherian property in this example is to apply a nice result of Cohen: a commutative ring is noetherian if every prime ideal is finitely generated (see Theorem 3.4 in Matsumura's "Commutative Ring Theory" for a clever elementary proof).

Comment: Nagata's Lemma E1.1 (that yields noetherianness of the example in question) is similarly elementary as Matsumura's proof (or the original proof) of Cohen's Theorem, but it finishes the whole thing.

Comment: +1 nosr.  Yes, I was implicitly assuming Cohen's theorem when I said the phrase Martin quoted.