# krull dimension

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

im looking for a non-noetherian ring with infinite krull dimension.would you help?

Comment: Take $k[x_,x_2,...]$. 

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119627/does-every-regular-noetherian-domain-have-finite-krull-dimension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A polynomial ring $k[X_1,X_2,\ldots]$ with an infinite number of variables will do. Finding a *noetherian* ring with infinite Krull dimension is harder (and first accomplished by Nagata).